# Facts about Divisibility

Tags: divisibility

I know that if $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$, then $a\mid sb+tc$ for all $s,t$.

Is this line below true?
$$a\mid c\land\forall s,t:a\mid sb+tc\implies a\mid b$$

Comment: And your conditions for the second line are for all $s,t$ right?

Comment: @ Parcly yes It is

Answer (score 1):

Since $a\mid c$, $a\mid tc$ for all $t$; since $a\mid sb+tc$, we can subtract $tc$ and obtain $a\mid sb$. Since this is true for all $s$, it is true for $s=1$, whereupon we have $a\mid b$.

Comment: Why not simply consider the case $s = 1$? That'd get you there even faster.

Comment: @JohnHughes Done.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your interpretation of your own question is not the right one. For if you're given that
$a \mid sb + tc$ for all integer $s$ and $t$, then choosing $s = 1, t = 0$ shows that $a \mid b$, and the other hypothesis involving $c$ isn't even needed.

I suspect that the right interpretation is this: suppose you know that for *some* $s$ and $t$, both 
$$
a \mid c \\
a \mid sb + tc.
$$

Can you conclude that $a | b$?

The answer is no. For instance, pick $a = c = s = 2, t = 0, b = 1$. Then you have that
$a \mid c$ because $2 \mid 2$, and $a \mid sb + tc $ because $2 \mid 2 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 2 = 2$, but it's *not* the case that $a \mid b$ because $2$ does not divide $1$.